# How to connect iphone/ipad with some other device through Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bluetooth, communication

I am developing an App which is suppose to establish communication with other device through Bluetooth but it is observed that iphone or ipad do not make connecting with other devices. or even they do not search other Bluetooth devices even within 1 feet area.

I want to make communication between them and I have to make a serial communication. Please tell me any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this (without jailbreaking your phone) you will need to enroll in Apple's MFI ('made for iPhone') program. This will give you access to the underlying external accessory framework.

The link is here: http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

It is not necessarily a straightforward application process. There is no way to do serial communication through bluetooth between iOS and a third-party accessory without this program.

Comment: Will it help to make Bluetooth communication with the device?

Comment: Yes. But you won't find much information about it here, due to the NDAs associated with the program.